# strange performance of postgres query

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Ive very strange problem, when I execute query like below:

```
with ap as (
    SELECT id from adress limit 1000)
)

SELECT distinct house.id, house.date
FROM house
WHERE house.adressid in (select id from ap)

LIMIT 9999
```

I ge the resulkts within 100 ms

But when I change the limit to 10 then Im getting a result after 20 s

```
    with ap as (
    SELECT id from adress limit 1000)
)

SELECT distinct house.id, house.date
FROM house
WHERE house.adressid in (select id from ap)

LIMIT 10
```

Of course there is index on adressid

```
CREATE INDEX house_idx
  ON house
  USING btree
  (adressid COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

In house there are like 9 mln rows.

Does anyone have an idea hoiw can I try to improve the performance. Ive reduces the problem to this very simple one but in reality the structure is much more complex thats why I didnt provide you with table create and query plans...

Comment: I'd start by using EXPLAIN ANALYZE to find out how postgresql is actually processing the two queries.

Comment: You may have oversimplified the query.  Postgres (unless it has some very unusual optimization) should be doing the same work for both queries -- it has to generate the entire list for the `select distinct` before the outer `limit` is applied.  There might be something else going on.

Comment: Actually this is the only thing that im changing

Answer (score 0):

That is actually not surprising:

In the first case `ap` has up to 1000 rows and the result set should have up to 9999, so the optimizer put `adress` first. With index on `house` query performance is relatively high.

In the second case `ap` still has up to 1000 rows, but the result set should have only up to 10, so the optimizer put `house` first... and ends up with 10 table scans on `adress` of up to 1000 rows each. It probably won't be able to even use an index since there is no Order By clause anywhere.

This `limit 1000` on address looks really suspicious and potentially can lead to inconsistent results: without `Order By` there is no guarantee which records from `adress` would be taken into account during each run.

I would use `INNER JOIN` to resolve the issue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT house.id, house.date
FROM house
INNER JOIN adress ON adress.id = house.adressid
ORDER BY house.date --< To add some consistency
LIMIT 10
```